# Is the difference in LRT definitions by Casella & Berger and other sources just difference in style?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I found that in Wikipedia and many other sources Likelihood Ratio Test Statistic is defined as
$$\lambda(x)=\frac{\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_1}{L(\theta)}}{\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_0}{L(\theta)}}$$
where $L(\theta)$ is the likelihood function. So the LRT is then formed as the rejection region for which the LRT statistic defined above is **greater** then some $k$.

On the other hand, in Statistical Inference by Casella & Berger LRT statistic is defined as
$$\lambda(x)=\frac{\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_0}{L(\theta)}}{\sup_{\theta\in\Theta}{L(\theta)}}$$ and test is formed as the region for some $k \leq 1$.

The only thing I concerned is the denominator. I was pretty sure Casella & Berger is the standard textbook and so I find this deviation confusing.

Could someone experienced point out is it just a difference in style/approach to the definition or Casella & Berger actually speak about some particular approach nowadays considered a non-standard one or something else? Thank you!

Comment: The LRT statistic in Casella/Berger is the standard one. Here you reject the null for small values of $\lambda$. Don't think the other version is correct to be honest.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, yeah, thanks you. Actually, I have made some research and figured out Casella's definition is indeed the standard and most convenient one. That one I asked about I found in Cambridge notes on statistics course for Part IB. Seems they got that definition from old editions of the DeGroot book (which they actually propose as a complementary, again 3rd edition, not 4th where the definition is as Casella's).

Comment: Well, fine, I like lecture notes from Cambridge Part IB course, though I really do not like deviations from standards... Will just skip that part :)